# Vue router-view not rending when using router.beforeEach

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm working with the Vue Router and I need to use the `router.beforeEach`callback to determine if a certain route has been hit. The only problem with this is that when the callback is used the `<router-view></router-view>` does not render anything.

`app.vue`

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <navComponent></navComponent>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import navComponent from './nav'
        export default {
            components: {
                navComponent
            }
        }
</script>
```

`routes.js`

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

export default new VueRouter({

    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: require('./views/home')
        },
        {
            path: '/logout'
        }
    ],

    linkActiveClass: 'is-active'
});
```

`app.js`

```
import './bootstrap';
import router from './routes';
import app from './views/app';

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {  //if this callback was commented out the <router-view></router-view> would render what i want it to render
    if(to.fullPath === '/logout') {
        axios.get('/logout');
        router.push('/');
    }
});

new Vue({

    el: "#app",

    router,

    render: h => h(app)

});
```

Sorry in advance if the fix is very simple, I just can't seem to find the solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

So it turns out I was missing the `next();` call within the `beforeEach` callback.

```
import './bootstrap';
import router from './routes';
import app from './views/app';

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if(to.fullPath === '/logout') {
        axios.get('/logout');
        router.push('/');
    }

    next(); //this is needed
});
```